# AWS API Gateway custom domain 404 error: Not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ssl-certificate

So I'm trying to set up a custom domain for my AWS Lambda function.

I went through all the instructions to buy a domain name via google domains, set up a certificate through AWS Certificate manager, and created the corresponding route 53 hosted zone.

[image]

For whatever reason, I unfortunately get a 403 error when I try to reach the API Gateway domain name endpoint. In this case, it's https://d-frdw0740fd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.

Also for context, here is my API mappings tab.

[image: API mappings tab]

For more context, here is my hosted zone in route 53 corresponding with my custom domain name:

[image: route 53]

Instead of bringing me to a `{"message": "Not Found"}` page, I'd like it to bring me to my actual aws endpoint.

Where am I going wrong in order to set up my configuration so that my API Gateway domain name is correctly linked to the functional aws endpoint instead of just reaching a 404 error?

UPDATE: I redeployed my serverless function and not instead of getting now instead of the 404 `Not Found` error I get 403 `Forbidden`:

```
{
"message": "Forbidden"
}
```

Comment: Please redeploy your api in stage and try again

Comment: Can you also share screenshot for the api mapping tab

Comment: @RohitAgarwal thank you for the help. I did redeploy my api however now I get `Forbidden` instead of `Not Found`. At least it's a new error, but seems like there's still a configuration problem.

Comment: @VikramS thanks for the help. I added a screenshot of my api mappings tab in the question description. Also for context I've tried adding a path such at `/test` to the mapping and then hitting `https://d-frdw0740fd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test` but i get the same result unfortunately

Comment: @Adrien You will be able to hit your API with  https://d-frdw0740fd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/  add the endpoint as per your deployment with HTTP method GET POST. Add /dev after the api gateway endpoint as you have defined stage /dev.The endpoint will always return Forbidden as it is better secured response.  Also the party-poll-api.com you will need to add the Route53 mapping for the API.

Comment: @VikramS I'm afraid that my custom domain API, d-frdw0740fd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev, is not working as it should since it just gives me the "Forbidden" response. For comparison, my  main invoke URL of the `dev` stage, https://1zofmxtv82.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev, gives me a `Missing Authentication Token` error which I would expect to hit on both API's.

Comment: @VikramS to further explain the problem, my main API has a health check endpoint that responds with "yay" to a simple GET request: https://1zofmxtv82.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/health-check

I expect the custom domain api url to work the same: https://d-frdw0740fd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/health-check however when I hit that endpoint it gives me "Forbidden" error.

I believe this endpoint should return "yay" as well, and until then I believe I have something improperly configured

Comment: @VikramS I believe I've set everything up properly on route 53 as well. I attached a screenshot of my configuration to give more context

Comment: Why I am saying the Route53 is not setup properly as the nslookup party-poll-api.com doesnt return any endpoints. The party-poll-api.com should resolve to some ip or domain.

Comment: Thanks you both, I was able to set up my custom domain name successfully, please see my answer for more detail

Answer (score 6):

Finally found the solution. I was previously trying to use the domain from Google domains but it’s just easier doing it all through route 53 registering a new domain which creates a hosted domain. For context, [this video was very helpful in getting me set up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ESei6XQ7dMg)

After following the steps in API gateway to create a certificate, custom domain, name, and api mapping, there’s one last step where you must add an A name DNS record that maps to the custom domain you just created.

One major step that I needed to take that I was failing to do was to [route the traffic from my gateway API to my domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-api-gateway.html#routing-to-api-gateway-config)

After doing that, I was able to successfully set up the custom domain name for the API.

Another major thing I learned was that under "Custom domain names", don't try to hit "API Gateway domain name" directly.

[image]

I tried so many times to hit this API and it was giving me that forbidden error, but it will always give that error even when the ACTUAL custom domain set up properly. So it is not useful to keep hitting this url to test that the domain is working properly, instead use the custom domain you've set up in route 53 to test to see if the setup is configured correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I have read your question and all comments and looks like the problem is in URL.

- **Problem**

As per the problem statement url [*Invoke URL*] **1zofmxtv82.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/health-check** is working as expected but url [*API Gateway Domain Name*] **d-frdw0740fd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/health-check** is giving 403 forbidden.

- **Solution**

There is no need to use stage name (dev) in this URL **d-frdw0740fd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/health-check**

Please try with **d-frdw0740fd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/health-check**

or try with Route53 URL

**party-poll-api.com/health-check**

- **Reason**

Stage name already included in API mapping so need to mention it again.

Comment: So I've tried hitting https://d-frdw0740fd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/health-check which is what I figured would be the correct URL but unfortunately I get back the 403 Forbidden error here

Comment: Ok what about Route53 URL that is also not working?